# Loading An Assembly Into An Application Domain With Lower Security

Tags: c#, .net, applicationdomain

I'm trying to create a Sandbox App Domain that has read only access to the file system. The code I have written to do this is

```
    var ps = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
    ps.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
    var f = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.None);
    f.AllLocalFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.Read;
    ps.AddPermission(f);

    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain",
        null,
        new AppDomainSetup { ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) },
        ps                
        );
    string pathToDll = @"c:\temp\test.dll";
    string thirdPartyFullName = "MyTest.Test";
    IPlugin myObject = (IPlugin)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToDll, thirdPartyFullName);
```

It *almost* works except it errors on the last line with this exception

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

If I change the FileIOPermission on the App Domain to have full access it runs fine. Is there something I need to change in Assembly I'm loading into the Application Domain to say it only needs read access to the file system?

I'm using .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably also need

```
FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h7t2a2.aspx

Comment: Thanks would never have found that.